# Convert subscribe to object

Tags: typescript, angular, mapping, observable, subscribe

I'm getting data from web service Doctor.service.ts :

```
*getAllDoctors():Observable<Doctor[]>{
let doctor$ = this.http
  .get(`${this.baseUrl}/users`,{headers: this.getHeaders()})
  .map(mapDoctor)
  return doctor$;}



*function mapDoctor(response:Response):Doctor[]{
return response.json().map(toDoctor);}




*function toDoctor(r:any):Doctor{
let doctor = <Doctor>({
id:r.id,
name:r.name,
username:r.username,
email:r.email,
phone:r.phone,
website:r.website,
company:r.company,
address:r.address,
});
console.log('Parsed doctor:', doctor);
return doctor;
}
```

in the component.ts , I'm getting this data like this :

```
doctors:Doctor[];

ngOnInit(){
this.doctorService
  .getAllDoctors()
  .subscribe(p => this.doctors = p);
}
```

The problem is that i want to use the list of doctors in others methods , like getting doctor by Key or getting List of doctors By ... , i have created this method :

```
getdoctorsById():Doctor[]{
return (this.doctors = this.doctors.filter(doctor => doctor.id ===   this.id));
}
```

But the problem is that the list of doctors is undefined ,it's not mapped to object Doctor , please i need some help !!!!!

Comment: Subscriptions work asynchronously. It is not guaranteed that the http request for the doctors has finished when you call the `getdoctorsById` function.

Comment: so , how should I proceed?

Comment: Could you post WHERE you call the getdoctorsById() function?

Comment: the true problem is that the doctors array ( getdoctor(){
    this.doctorService
      .getAllDoctors()
      .subscribe(p => this.doctors = p); ) is not an array of doctor object (or doctor entity Doctor.ts ), this is the gist : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/17096098516467081de12a9e33fb1764

Comment: `getAllDoctors()` returns `Observable`, then you `subscribe`. Inside subscribe `p` will be resolved as `Doctor[]`. Looks correct.

Comment: So , what do you thin about this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Each time you want to access `this.doctors` you have to check if it contains elements and return an **empty array** if not:

```
getdoctorsById():Doctor[] {
  if (!this.doctors.length)
    return [];

  return (this.doctors = this.doctors.filter(doctor => doctor.id === this.id));
}
```

**Update**: I think I see the problem. Try to declare your array of `doctors` like this:

```
doctors:Doctor[] = [];
```

By this you initialize this array by an empty array.

**Update2**:

In your `DoctorService` (file `NestedJson.service.ts`) you declare and access `this.doctors` the same way as before:

```
doctors:Doctor[];

...

function toDoctor(r:any):Doctor{
  let doctor = <Doctor>({
    id:r.id,
    name:r.name,
    username:r.username,
    email:r.email,
    phone:r.phone,
    website:r.website,
    company:r.company,
    address:r.address,

  });
  console.log('Parsed doctor:', doctor);
  this.doctors.push(doctor); // <== this.doctors === undefined here
  console.log('MMMMMMMMMMMMM',this.doctors);
  return doctor;
}
```

So, initialize it the same with an **empty array**

**Update3**: Change `getdoctorsById`:

```
getdoctorsById():Doctor[]{
  return this.doctors.filter(doctor => doctor.id ===   this.id);
}
```

I.e. remove assignment.

Comment: the problem is that I can't use doctors like Doctor object

Comment: You always have to check if there are items in array before accessing an element by index. However if you use this empty array in a *template*, `ngFor` won't executed, because there are no elements.

Comment: the error persist : TypeError: Cannot read property 'doctors' of undefined  , this is the gist : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/17096098516467081de12a9e33fb1764

Comment: His issue is about the asynchronous nature of the http callback. The fact that the doctor list is undefined is just a symptome.

Comment: in the NestedJson.service.ts , I initialized the doctors array (empty ) and the same error persist  (TypeError: Cannot read property 'doctors' of undefined) , I think the problem is that the doctors array isn't an array of doctor object !!

Comment: You might be right, but it's hard to tell. If he calls the getDoctorsById() method too early, e.g. later in ngOnInit, it is definitely a concurrency issue.

Comment: if we supposed that there is no getDoctorsById() method , when i want to print the array of doctors in the console , the error is that the doctors array is undefined